# Folium plot GeoJson fill color in polygon based on custom values

Tags: python, geopandas, folium, choropleth

I have polygons with lat/long values associated with identifiers in a `GeoDataFrame` as shown below. Consider an example with two identifiers `A` and `B`, polygon `A` has three points and `B` has four points, their lat/long values are as shown below. Corresponding to each point (lat/long), I also have an associated numeric value as shown in the last column.

```
id    geometry                                                                         values
A   POLYGON((lat_A_1 long_A_1, lat_A_2 long_A_2, lat_A_3 long_A_3))                    10,12,13
B   POLYGON((lat_B_1 long_B_1, lat_B_2 long_B_2, lat_B_3 long_B_3, lat_B_4 long_B_4))  4,8,16,20
```

I iterate over the GeoDataFrame and plot these polygons on the map using this code

```
    geo_j = folium.GeoJson(data=geo_j,
                           style_function={ 
                               'fillColor': 'blue'
                           })
```

Is there a way that I can fill the polygon with a custom colormap based on the column `values` in the GeoDataFrame, such as red for 0-5, blue for 6-10 and green for 11-20. How can this be done?

Comment: I have a question about the question. Is there three values for one polygon? So if I handle the process in a loop, it will overwrite the values, right? There is a way to create a custom color map and change the color based on the values. See [this page](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/Colormaps.ipynb).

Comment: Three values if there are three vertices of the polygon, four values for the second polygon as it has four vertices.

Comment: You want to fill in the polygons, right? Isn't there a single value for the fill color?

Comment: I want to define a colormap like red for 0-5, blue for 6-10 and green for 11-20. Using this, for polygon B, I want area around vertex 1 to be red (for value 4), area around vertex 2 and 3 to be blue (for values 8,6) and area around vertex 4 to be green (for value 20). The interior of the polygon should be filled progressively be extrapolating vertex colors using the colormap.

Comment: For such a requirement, it would be easier to use the data in point coordinates rather than polygon coordinates. If you want to use markers to fill in each coordinate, please refer to the following examples of [circle markers](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/GeoJSONMarker.ipynb) and [color maps](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/Colormaps.ipynb).

Comment: That wouldn't address the requirement. The polygon represents a region on the map, and we know the values of a quantity of interest at the vertices of this polygon. We want to fill the polygon with a colormap that extrapolates gradient color based on value at the vertices.

Comment: there's a fundamental I can't guess what you mean...  the colors are defined by points,  but you want to fill based on a polygon, that is many points.  If some points are represented by 0-5 and others by 6-10 in same polygon.  what color do I choose?

Comment: @RobRaymond, the fill color needs to be a gradient fill, based on the colors at the vertices, something like this if the polygon was a triangle (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcpIj.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- started by getting some polygons and defining a value per point (generate MWE sample data set)
- this means you have as many values associated with polygon as there are points in the polygon.  You request a solution using **folium** that fills the polygon with a custom color map value.  This means you need to have a function that will assimilates all these values into a single value for the polygon (a color).  I have used **mode**, most common value.  This could be mean, median or any other function.
- solution then become simple, it's `folium.GeoJson()` using and appropriately structured **style_function**
- extended answer.  You can split polygon into smaller polygons and associate color of sub-polygon with a point.  **folium** production is unchanged (have include *iso_a3*) just to make it simpler to view
- **shapley** provides two ways to split a polygon https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.triangulate. Have found that *voronoi* is more effective

#### generate MWE data

```
# some polygons
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres")).loc[lambda d: d["iso_a3"].isin(["BEL", "LUX", "NLD", "DEU", "AUT"]), ["geometry"]]

# comma separated values column... between 0 and 20...
gdf["values"] = gdf.geometry.apply(lambda p: ",".join([str(int(sum(xy)) % 20) for xy in p.exterior.coords]))
# id column
gdf["id"] = list("ABCDEFGHIJ")[0 : len(gdf)]
gdf = gdf.set_index("id", drop=False)
```

#### data

```
                                   geometry                                   values id
id                                                                                     
A   POLYGON ((16.97967 48.12350, 16.9037...  5,4,4,4,3,2,1,1,0,19,19,18,17,17,16,...  A
B   POLYGON ((14.11969 53.75703, 14.3533...  7,7,7,7,6,6,6,5,5,4,4,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,...  B
C   POLYGON ((6.04307 50.12805, 6.24275 ...                     16,16,15,15,15,15,16  C
D   POLYGON ((6.15666 50.80372, 6.04307 ...  16,16,15,15,14,14,13,13,13,13,14,14,...  D
E   POLYGON ((6.90514 53.48216, 7.09205 ...  0,0,19,18,17,16,16,16,15,14,14,15,17...  E
```

#### solution

```
import statistics as st
import branca.colormap
import geopandas as gpd
import folium

m = folium.Map(
    location=[
        sum(gdf.geometry.total_bounds[[1, 3]]) / 2,
        sum(gdf.geometry.total_bounds[[0, 2]]) / 2,
    ],
    zoom_start=5,
    control_scale=True,
)

# style the polygons based on "values" property
def style_fn(feature):
    cm = branca.colormap.LinearColormap(["mistyrose", "tomato", "red"], vmin=0, vmax=20)
    most_common = st.mode([int(v) for v in feature["properties"]["values"].split(",")])
    ss = {
        "fillColor": cm(most_common),
        "fillOpacity": 0.8,
        "weight": 0.8,
        "color": cm(most_common),
    }
    return ss


folium.GeoJson(
    gdf.__geo_interface__,
    style_function=style_fn,
    tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(["id", "values"]),
).add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

#### split polygons into parts

```
import statistics as st
import branca.colormap
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
import shapely.geometry
import shapely.ops
import pandas as pd

# some polygons
# fmt: off
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres")).loc[lambda d: d["iso_a3"].isin(["BEL", "LUX", "NLD", "DEU", "AUT","POL"]), ["geometry", "iso_a3"]]

# comma separated values column... between 0 and 20...
gdf["values"] = gdf.geometry.apply(lambda p: ",".join([str(int(sum(xy)) % 20) for xy in p.exterior.coords]))
# id column
gdf["id"] = list("ABCDEFGHIJ")[0 : len(gdf)]
gdf = gdf.set_index("id", drop=False)
# fmt: on


def sub_polygons(r, method="voronoi"):
    g = r["geometry"]
    # split into sub-polygons
    if method == "voronoi":
        geoms = shapely.ops.voronoi_diagram(g).geoms
    elif method == "triangulate":
        geoms = [
            p
            for p in shapely.ops.triangulate(g)
            if isinstance(p.intersection(g), shapely.geometry.Polygon)
        ]
    else:
        raise "invalid polygon ops method"
        
    # clip sub-geometries
    geoms = [p.intersection(g) for p in geoms]
    vs = r["values"].split(",")
    vr = []
    # order or sub-polygons and points are differenct.  use value from point
    # in sub-polygon
    for vg in geoms:
        for i, xy in enumerate(g.exterior.coords):
            if not shapely.geometry.Point(xy).intersection(vg).is_empty:
                break
        vr.append(vs[i])
    return [{**r.to_dict(), **{"geometry": g, "values": v}} for g, v in zip(geoms, vr)]


gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    gdf.apply(sub_polygons, axis=1, method="voronoi").explode().apply(pd.Series)
)


m = folium.Map(
    location=[
        sum(gdf.geometry.total_bounds[[1, 3]]) / 2,
        sum(gdf.geometry.total_bounds[[0, 2]]) / 2,
    ],
    zoom_start=5,
    control_scale=True,
)

# style the polygons based on "values" property
def style_fn(feature):
    cm = branca.colormap.LinearColormap(["mistyrose", "tomato", "red"], vmin=0, vmax=20)
    most_common = st.mode([int(v) for v in feature["properties"]["values"].split(",")])
    ss = {
        "fillColor": cm(most_common),
        "fillOpacity": 0.8,
        "weight": 0.8,
        "color": cm(most_common),
    }
    return ss


folium.GeoJson(
    gdf2.__geo_interface__,
    style_function=style_fn,
    tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(["id", "values", "iso_a3"]),
).add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

#### with FeatureGroup

```
m = folium.Map(
    location=[
        sum(gdf.geometry.total_bounds[[1, 3]]) / 2,
        sum(gdf.geometry.total_bounds[[0, 2]]) / 2,
    ],
    zoom_start=5,
    control_scale=True,
)

for g, d in gdf2.groupby(level=0):
    fg = folium.map.FeatureGroup(name=g)
    folium.GeoJson(
        d.__geo_interface__,
        style_function=style_fn,
        tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(["id", "values", "iso_a3"]),
    ).add_to(fg)
    fg.add_to(m)
    
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)    
m
```

Comment: Thanks for this, there is a small difference with what I was looking for, here you are filling each polygon with a single color which is the color corresponding the mode of the values at the vertices. What I wanted was to fill the polygon with multiple colors (like a gradient fill) where the gradient color is extrapolated from the colors at the vertices. Would that be possible?

Comment: I've updated answer - polygons have only one fill color. To have multiple colors, split polygon into multiple sub-polygons and pick sub-polygon color from fact a point is within it.

Comment: Would it also be possible to add a `FeatureGroup` corresponding to the polygons here to select the `id` values to be shown on the map?

Comment: yes - very straight forward - added to answer