# Create map boundaries from points within a geodataframe in python

Tags: python, mapping, gis, geopandas

I have a geodataframe called `map` which contains a list of points and a column, `Closest_TrainStation_name` which contains the name of the closest train station to that point.

|  | geometry | Closest_TrainStation_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | POINT(1,1) | Station_1 |
| 2 | POINT(10,10) | Station_2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Is it possible to create boundary polygons containing each group like in the picture below? With each polygon having the name of the nearest train station from the original file.

The points were made using a nearest neighbour algorithm so they won't intersect with each other.

I also have a boundary geodataframe for the whole country called `boundary` which I think might be needed for defining the outer bounds of this map. And a file of the train stations.

[image: Map of the points with the nearest train station]

All of the methods I can find are about making boundaries from points on the boundary, e.g. convex_hull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- have used hospitals in England as source of data (effectively station and hospital and interchangeable)
- have geometry that is boundary of England (to clip Voronoi polygons)
- it then becomes simple to generate polygons that represent all the hospitals
- use `sjoin()` to associate polygon with point that carries all the associated attributes
- have used **plotly** to visualize and demonstrate polygons have hospital attributes associated with them

```
import shapely.ops

# points for hospitals
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=dfhos.loc[:, ["Longitude", "Latitude"]].apply(
        shapely.geometry.Point, axis=1
    )
)

# generate voroni polygon for each hospital
gdfv = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[
        p.intersection(uk)
        for p in shapely.ops.voronoi_diagram(
            shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(gdf["geometry"].values)
        ).geoms
    ]
)

# spatial join polygons to points to pick up full details of hospital
gdf3 = gpd.sjoin(gdfv, gdf, how="left").merge(
    dfhos, left_on="index_right", right_index=True
)
gdf3["Color"] = pd.factorize(gdf3["Postcode"], sort=True)[0]

# and visualize
fig = (
    px.choropleth_mapbox(
        gdf3,
        geojson=gdf3.__geo_interface__,
        locations=gdf3.index,
        hover_data=["OrganisationCode","OrganisationName","Postcode"],
        color="Color",
        color_continuous_scale="phase",
    )
    .update_layout(
        mapbox={
            "style": "carto-positron",
            "center": {
                "lon": sum(gdf3.total_bounds[[0, 2]]) / 2,
                "lat": sum(gdf3.total_bounds[[1, 3]]) / 2,
            },
            "zoom": 5,
        },
        margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
        coloraxis={"showscale":False}
    )
)

fig
```

[image]

#### get locations of hospitals in England and polygon that is boundary of England

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import requests, io
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib
import pandas as pd

# fmt: off
# uk geometry
url = "http://geoportal1-ons.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/687f346f5023410ba86615655ff33ca9_1.zip"
f = Path.cwd().joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1])

if not f.exists():
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
    with open(f, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
    zfile = ZipFile(f)
    zfile.extractall(f.stem)

f2 = Path.cwd().joinpath("uk.geojson")
if not f2.exists():
    gdf2 = gpd.read_file(list(f.parent.joinpath(f.stem).glob("*.shp"))[0])
    gdf2 = gdf2.loc[gdf2["ctyua16cd"].str[0] == "E"]
    uk = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[p for p in shapely.ops.unary_union(gdf2.to_crs(gdf2.estimate_utm_crs())["geometry"].values).simplify(5000).geoms]).set_crs(gdf2.estimate_utm_crs()).to_crs("EPSG:4326")

    uk.to_file(Path.cwd().joinpath("uk.geojson"), driver='GeoJSON')
uk = gpd.read_file(f2)
uk = shapely.geometry.MultiPolygon(uk["geometry"].values)
# fmt: on

# get hospitals in UK
dfhos = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(requests.get("https://assets.nhs.uk/data/foi/Hospital.csv").text),sep="Č",engine="python",)
dfhos = dfhos.loc[lambda d: d["Sector"].eq("NHS Sector") & d["SubType"].eq("Hospital")].groupby("ParentODSCode").first()
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- have generated some sample data
- using combination of https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/aggregation_with_dissolve.html to generate a *MultiPoint* **shapely** object then `convex_hull` will give you a bounding polygon for associated points

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.wkt

df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """geometry,stationname
POINT (6.84365570015329 53.29316918283323),station 0
POINT (6.84397077786025 53.34219781242178),station 0
POINT (6.86411903336562 53.31761406936343),station 0
POINT (6.818510924831408 53.31265038241855),station 0
POINT (6.56484740742038 53.29280081541883),station 1
POINT (6.626702808494024 53.28117175507543),station 1
POINT (6.593563692631294 53.3071306760684),station 1
POINT (6.578341784305515 53.33493210605594),station 1
POINT (6.622799032233983 53.28010824623466),station 1
POINT (6.613683981274606 53.29073387043917),station 1
POINT (7.132754969933528 53.04549586270261),station 2
POINT (7.198050554432563 53.1025440484535),station 2
POINT (7.129751539288898 53.05572095828281),station 2
POINT (7.176645494114577 53.11826239684777),station 2
POINT (7.197200682695362 53.07260800358519),station 2
POINT (7.162805175737367 53.10861252890756),station 2
POINT (7.109351059746762 53.13349222863155),station 2
POINT (7.06391508890864 53.11204313452662),station 2
POINT (7.184832998096279 53.05647939687099),station 2
POINT (7.159339780758176 53.06749816133893),station 2
POINT (7.107083795756558 53.08269279330896),station 2
POINT (7.023547595125693 53.07391566675645),station 2
POINT (7.150033380903857 53.1339122880752),station 2
POINT (7.087567734179277 53.13629412269268),station 2
POINT (7.082082576050039 53.09928180316115),station 2
POINT (7.163037435775678 53.10643603535302),station 2
POINT (7.188994818425656 53.11808478608855),station 2
POINT (7.096403367400944 53.09224186363327),station 2
POINT (7.166715752727275 53.13534692250609),station 2
POINT (7.153873895859038 53.15187182174655),station 2"""
    )
)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=df["geometry"].apply(shapely.wkt.loads)).dissolve(
    "stationname"
)["geometry"].apply(lambda mp: mp.convex_hull)

gdf.plot()
```

[image]

| stationname | geometry |
| --- | --- |
| station 0 | POLYGON ((6.84365570015329 53.29316918283323, 6.818510924831408 53.31265038241855, 6.84397077786025 53.34219781242178, 6.86411903336562 53.31761406936343, 6.84365570015329 53.29316918283323)) |
| station 1 | POLYGON ((6.622799032233983 53.28010824623466, 6.56484740742038 53.29280081541883, 6.578341784305515 53.33493210605594, 6.626702808494024 53.28117175507543, 6.622799032233983 53.28010824623466)) |
| station 2 | POLYGON ((7.132754969933528 53.04549586270261, 7.023547595125693 53.07391566675645, 7.087567734179277 53.13629412269268, 7.153873895859038 53.15187182174655, 7.188994818425656 53.11808478608855, 7.198050554432563 53.1025440484535, 7.197200682695362 53.07260800358519, 7.184832998096279 53.05647939687099, 7.132754969933528 53.04549586270261)) |

Comment: thank you for taking the time to comment. This isn't quite what I was after. Apparently what I wanted was a Voronoi diagram. How to make them is explained here https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-voronoi-regions-with-geospatial-data-in-python-adbb6c5f2134

Comment: I've used voroni diagram in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70030163/folium-plot-geojson-fill-color-in-polygon-based-on-custom-values/70113891#70113891  I don't see how it applies in this case as polygons are effectively already defined through station name.  make you question more specific,  what country,  sample points etc?  I'll take a look