# How can to convert a shapely polygon dict to geojson format

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I am new to shapely and am running into a small issue with the format, and I hope someone here can help me, or point me in the right direction.

I am constructing voronoi polygons, by using this package: geovoronoi
https://github.com/WZBSocialScienceCenter/geovoronoi/blob/master/examples/using_geopandas.py

And the instructions are clear, and the plot of the polygons looks good, but now I would like to use the polygons. When checking the object I see this:

```
Type:        dict
String form: {0: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000029A9E47F6D0>, 1: <shapely.geometry.polygon <...> ject at 0x0000029AA8B08CA0>, 41: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000029AA8B08D00>}
Length:      42
```

So, that is good, but how do I convert this polygon object to something more useful, like a geojson or geopandas dataframe? It must be something very basic, but as I am new to this format I might have missed it while reading the documentation.
Thanks in advance,
Gijs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: yeah it's not quite clear what you're working with, since the snippet you posted isn't python. but you can create a GeoDataFrame from a list of shapes by simply passing a list as the geometry arg, e.g. `geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=list(geometries))` so if you're working with a dictionary with shapely Polygon values, you could do `list(geometries.values())`.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, I am sorry for not giving code, but I am following the tutorial in my original post, and successfully get the output of the function below.

<br>
`# calculate the regions
# we set "per_geom=False" so that the whole continent is treated as one area and Voronoi regions
# span over to Tierra del Fuego
region_polys, region_pts = voronoi_regions_from_coords(coords, south_am_shape, per_geom=False)`
<br>

region_polys is the dict, and has 42 elements, but I don't know how to unpack this dict.

Comment: The documentation is saying `region_polys is a dict that maps Voronoi region IDs to shapely Polygon objects that represent the shape of the respective Voronoi region. With them, you can do everything that the shapely API provides. You can, for example, get each Voronoi region's area (there's also a helper function calculate_polygon_areas in geovoronoi for that).`

Comment: `print(type(region_polys))
<class 'dict'>

print(type(region_polys[0]))
<class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>`

Comment: yeah - so you should be able to do this: `geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=list(region_polys.values()))` does that work? If you need to add clarification to your question please edit the question so it's more clear rather than putting a ton of formatted text in the comments.

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Would you have the documentation for this, I might have missed it? If I get it right:
list is converting the dict, and the only value is an object "geometry" which fits the geometry requirements of the GeoDataFrame.

Next time I will try to edit the question (didn't see the option)

Comment: I have answered a few questions using voroni. both pull out geojson and use in either folium or plotly  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70159305/create-map-boundaries-from-points-within-a-geodataframe-in-python/70169765#70169765. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70030163/folium-plot-geojson-fill-color-in-polygon-based-on-custom-values/70113891#70113891

Comment: @RobRaymond, thank you for the links, I will check your voronoi methods - this question was more about unpacking the `dict` coming from the method to generate the polygons; apologies for the confusion.